# How to test Stripe Connect connected account creations

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to use `Stripe Connect` to provide multiparty payments, in my website.

I have a platform. User A (customer) will pay User B (which is the service provider) on the platform and as a platform, I want to get some amount percentage in the middle.

So, I'm following this guide
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide

But, when it comes to testing creating those `standard` connected accounts, I need to fill real information like phones and emails.

However, I found this guide to fullfill my problem:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#using-oauth

But, I'm not sure how can I use this guide?
How can I create a stripe account for my user B (who will accept payment through my platform) and got that `account_id` in testing (and later production)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple points to clear:

1. There are Standard, Express and Custom account types. There are also
   3 fund flows of Direct Charge, Destination Charge, or Separate
   Charges and Transfers. See [comparison from Stripe Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges#types) *(this is important)*
2. If you decide to use Standard Account, you should go with Direct
   Charges
3. There are 2 ways to onboard a Standard Account. OAuth is a
   legacy integration. [Account Link is preferable](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts).
4. But really, [Express + Destination Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges) would be easier. You should also use [Account Link to create express accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts)

Comment: orakaro, Thanks. I'm using Standard and direct charges. I've redirected the user to an account link using [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts). But don't know how to test it. It asks for real information. It did create an `account` in dashboard but if I can't fill those real info, I can't do payouts or other features.

Comment: In the connect dashboard, those accounts are all `restricted`, which means they can't do any payment and payouts function because they haven't filled in real bank acc info. So, how can I stimulate real ones?

Comment: You can try the test data from here https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stripe Onboarder to onboard Express accounts.
https://github.com/sponsorkit/stripe-onboarder

It is unfortunate that Stripe does not have an option for doing this programmatically. Everything seems to be manual, so Stripe Onboarder uses Puppeteer (browser automation) for this.