# Stripe Connect with Standard accounts onboarding (flow)

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a hard time to understand Stripe Connect with **Standard** accounts onboarding...and testing the whole integration.
The more i read about, the more i get confused.

**Onboarding**
Two scenarios are usally applicable: Connect existing accounts OR allow users to create a Stripe account.
Until now i prepared to use:
a) OAuth for existing accounts
b) Stripe hosted flow for creating new accounts
However, the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72226684/801018) states that OAuth is a legacy integration and 'Account Link' is preferable.
Is 'Account Link' the recommended way for existing accounts as well (no OAuth)?
Because the official documentation states something different
[image]

**Testing (onboarding new accounts)**
I am successful in creating a new account and redirecting to Stripe flow.
Since verifiication needs entering a phone number, i should be able to skip the form entirely (in test mode)...but i have no such option.
That option is only available in OAuth.
However (whether using the API, or creating user from within the dashboard), **created accounts are 'restricted' and useless to use for testing** payments on_behalf_of etc etc

Kindly help me out here, because i was expecting that onboarding of existing/new accounts would be easier and done programmatically from one interface only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating Stripe Accounts via the Stripe API and then creating an Account Link to onboard those accounts is the recommended approach.  However, that approach only works if you don't need to connect to existing Stripe Accounts.

If you do need to connect to existing Stripe Accounts you should use the OAuth flow, which allows you to connect to existing Stripe Accounts and also allows your users to create a new Stripe Account if they don't already have one.

You should not mix the two approaches, you should pick one or the other based on your needs.

For testing, the onboarding behavior differences you encountered are expected, as the two approaches are different.  As far as functionality goes, test mode operations should work despite the accounts being in a restricted status.

Comment: Thank you Justin for the clarification. That means, not both approaches are necessary. Then in my case, for onboarding (new & existing accounts) OAuth will be sufficient to cover both cases? That was not clear in the documentation or i might have missed something

Comment: Yes, that's correct, you only need to use OAuth.  People going through onboarding will be asked to link an existing or new Stripe account to your platform.